# automatic timestamp script for each row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, timestamp, automatic-properties

I'm looking for a script for google sheet that automatically inserts a timestamp for each row. and the date and time will be updated every time any of the rows gets edited. Timestamp will be put on column 1 and the rows can be the whole rows after the row 1, no specific number of rows. Please help I am very new at this. Need it badly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) from Google Apps Script.

To do that, open a script bound to your spreadsheet by clicking `Tools > Script editor`, copy the following code and save the project:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if (row > 1) { // Check edited row is not first one
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"); // Format you want the timestamp, edit accordingly
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 1).setValue(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Ill recommend this to my friends. Thank you;;)))

Comment: @ashleytago You're welcome. Also, would you please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if you consider it helpful? This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.